# Detecting mouse action with neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

Inspired by sentdex Python plays GTA V series (https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5), I decided to try some machine learning.

Long story short - I made an app, which creates random red and blue filled ellipses. One at a time. App sets cursor over ellipses and press mouse button according to color. That way I captured ~250k frames(128x96 in 50 files with 5k frames each) with mouse position(18 bits - 8 bits X, 8 bits Y an 2 bits for mouse buttons) and fed it to neural network(googlenet inception). Learning rate was set to 0.001.
[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4Gbu.jpg) shows graph after training. It stopped at ~0.22 accuracy. I thought it's a total disaster, but I decided to test the model, and it actually did quiet good.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhxve.gif) is the model playing. It makes 15% misclicks over few thousand samples, and those misclicks aren't that much off.

Before diving into more complex environment, I'd like to ask if this approach is any good? What is considered a good sample for the network in a more complex stuff? Is 0.22 accuracy decent for that kind of task, or are there any ways to improve that score? I use tensorflow with tflearn.

Comment: I suspect there's no definitive answer because: 1) "Good" is defined relative to *your* requirements for the task, so you get to decide what that means. For coarse perspective, it looks like the maximum *possible* performance in your example is 100% accuracy, which a simple program should be able to achieve with no learning at all. 2) It's not clear what "more complex stuff" is. 22% misclassification rate of pedestrians by self-driving cars would leave the streets littered with bodies. In other applications, 22% could be quite good.

Comment: @user20160 I've copied your comment as an answer. If you would like to write your own answer, please let me know and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's no definitive answer because: 1) "Good" is defined relative to your requirements for the task, so you get to decide what that means. For coarse perspective, it looks like the maximum possible performance in your example is 100% accuracy, which a simple program should be able to achieve with no learning at all. 2) It's not clear what "more complex stuff" is. 22% misclassification rate of pedestrians by self-driving cars would leave the streets littered with bodies. In other applications, 22% could be quite good.

---

I've copied @user20160's comment as an answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

- [Are we seeing a dramatic drop in answers per question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/are-we-seeing-a-dramatic-drop-in-answers-per-question/5320#5320)
- [Comments that are actually answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers)
- [We have a very large & widening gap between questions and answers. How do we fix it?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix)